# Advice on how to analyse “customer-data” in R

Tags: r, anova, clustering, cart, k-means

consider the following example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(customer=c(rep("customer1",5),rep("customer2",10),rep("customer3",7)),
                  money_spent=sample(22))

df2 <- data.frame(customer=c("customer1","customer2","customer3"),
                  origin=c("US","US","UK"),
                  industry_sector=c("IS1","IS2","IS3"),
                  currency=c("USD","USD","GBP"))
```

My actual data consists of about 200000 rows and I would like to examine it in terms of, for instance, do customers from the US spent more money compared to customers from other countries. I would also like to see whether the amount of money spent depends on the industry sector and so on. I have some more explanatory variables apart from origin, industry sector and currency which I would like to look into. Also the number of records for the customers differ so that it might make sense to average the money spent for each customer.

I am not sure about how to best analyse this data. I first thought of cluster analysis, in particular, hierarchical clustering but am not sure whether it can be applied to such data and, in particular, how to structure the data to be put into the function. The R function `hclust` takes a matrix as the input but how would I structure such a matrix in terms of my data? Could k-means clustering be a better alternative?

Another approach would probably to analyse this data using boxplots and an one-way ANOVA approach to see whether "money spent" differs between different countries or industry sectors. However, this approach does not test whether the variables are dependend on each other. To look into this, I have been advised to apply a decision tree first and then do some statistical significance analysis. However, from what I have read so far I cannot see how decision trees can help me to detect variable dependencies.

So, I am wondering whether there any other/better techniques/functions out there which are more suitable for such data? Maybe a time series analysis is more appropriate since we have also recorded the dates when customers spent money.

Comment: Your issue seems to be calling *exactly* for ANOVA, especially since you seem to be interested more in causal relationships than in, e.g., prediction. What do you mean by "this approach does not test whether the variables are dependend on each other"? Are you looking for interaction terms in ANOVA? Clustering will not help you much in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, in the fist instance we won't use the data for prediction but may do so later on. Can decision trees used for that kind of analysis then? With "this approach does not test whether the variables are dependend on each other" I mean, for instance, that a difference in countries can be influenced by industry sectors which might be quite different between the countries tested. Can't I test this using regression analysis by comparing the different models fitted with different predictor variables (country, industry sector etc.)? Or am I confusing something here?

Comment: You can use regression trees and similar techniques (Random Forests etc.) to predict, and you can do sensitivity analyses. If you are looking for p values, use ANOVA. Interactions between sectors and countries can be modeled within ANOVA by using interaction terms.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know whether this data can also be used with cluster analysis? I think my first thought was wrong though as I cannot see how to construct a matrix for cluster analysis with this data since for all expalantory vars (origin, industry, etc.) the value "money spent" is the same! Or would we construct the matrix in a different way which I do not see at the moment?

Comment: As I wrote above: I don't see how clustering can help you here. Clustering is inherently an unsupervised learning algorithm, but you do have a target variable, the spend per customer, so you should use a supervised learning technique. I suggest you go with ANOVA. I would not advise using a technique you do not understand.

Comment: Well, I share zour opinion. I was just wondering in general whether it would be possible to stuck this data into a cluster analysis formating the matrix as I have mentioned above. I go for ANOVA and see how that works out :) Many thanks!